# VB6 and ActiveMQ

Tags: vb6, activemq-classic

how can I consume topics in ActiveMQ with VB6? Is there any other way besides using the REST API?

Comment: what's wrong with the REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the STOMP transport? http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html . STOMP supports .NET clients - http://stomp.codehaus.org/DotNet .

Also Apache Camel can bridge JMS to protocol you desire.

Comment: Unfortunetely I need a VB6 solution :(

Comment: You can easily communicate with STOMP-based transport of running ActiveMQ even with Telnet :) You just send string messages indicating communication phase (like CONNECT, SEND, SUBSCRIBE, COMMIT etc.) and message-related data itself. STOMP is cool because it makes easy to create a client in any language supporting TCP connection. You don't have to use language-specific STOMP library.

Comment: BTW if you decided to use STOMP and need help with that - let me know here.